# three js blend two background image

Tags: three.js

I made a game, which has a ground mesh with green image material, what I want to do is when a specific event happens, let say a button is clicked, the background image could gradually become to another image, like blend, but I don't know which function in threejs could do that.

Comment: Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: There are a couple of ways to achieve it, like writing your own `shader` to mix two image together smoothly, but the easiest way is to make a textured canvas and simply fade in an image bit by. THis has a lot of edge cases though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way to do it is to simply use a `canvas` as texture and redraw the `canvas` element itself. The downside here is that the updated canvas needs to be brought into the drawing buffer every time you change it's value, so it's not ideal, but it can work (click the renderer to fade the texture):

```js
// I have compressed this function as its just an utility to just draw a circle in two colors to use as example images and prevent cross-origin issues.
function anImage( color1, color2 ){ var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' ), ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' ); canvas.width = 256; canvas.height = 256; ctx.fillStyle = color1; ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, 400, 400 ); ctx.fillStyle = color2; ctx.arc( 200, 200, 200, 0, Math.PI * 2 ); ctx.fill(); return canvas; }

function drawTexture(){
 
 // Draw the first image full opaque
 
 ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

 ctx.drawImage( image1, 0, 0, 512, 512 );

 // Draw the second image as transparent as its transition requires
 
 ctx.globalAlpha = state;

 ctx.drawImage( image2, 0, 0, 512, 512 );

 texture.needsUpdate = true;

}
function render(){

 state = targetState >= state ? state + .01 : state - .01;
 state = state < 0 ? 0 : state > 1 ? 1 : state;

 drawTexture();
 
 cube.rotation.y += .01;

 renderer.render( scene, camera );

 window.requestAnimationFrame( render );

}

var image1 = anImage( 'red', 'yellow' );
var image2 = anImage( 'blue', 'green' );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
var scene = new THREE.Scene;
var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
var state = 0;
var targetState = 0;

// Lets set up our canvas for the texture

canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 512;

ctx.drawImage( image1, 0, 0, 512, 512 );

var texture = new THREE.Texture( canvas );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry,
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture })
);

scene.add( cube );

camera.position.set( 0, 0, 5 );
camera.lookAt( scene.position );

renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
 targetState = targetState === 1 ? 0 : 1
});
renderer.setSize( 512, 512 );

render();

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
```

The second way is to use a special `ShaderMaterial` that you can construct yourself. It asks for some uniforms (which will include our `textures`) and a value we can modify that we are going to call `fade`, which will be our *state*. Then we need to write our own `vertex` shader - which is easy, we just use the default position we can find in the THREE.js docs. Then we need to add our `fragment` shader, which will color our pixels. Here we read our colors at that point and mix them together. We also had to bring over the `uv` from the `vertex` shader, so we know where to look for our pixels. This method is more efficient, as the textures are buffered once and never touched after, letting our GPU handle the heavy lifting.

```js
function anImage( color1, color2 ){ var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' ), ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' ); canvas.width = 256; canvas.height = 256; ctx.fillStyle = color1; ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, 400, 400 ); ctx.fillStyle = color2; ctx.arc( 200, 200, 200, 0, Math.PI * 2 ); ctx.fill(); return canvas; }
function render(){

  state = targetState >= state ? state + .01 : state - .01;
  state = state < 0 ? 0 : state > 1 ? 1 : state;
 
  // Set the fade value in the uniforms
  cube.material.uniforms.fade.value = state;
  cube.rotation.y += .01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

  window.requestAnimationFrame( render );

}

var texture1 = new THREE.Texture( anImage( 'red', 'yellow' ) );
var texture2 = new THREE.Texture( anImage( 'blue', 'green' ) );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
var scene = new THREE.Scene;
var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
var state = 0;
var targetState = 0;

texture1.needsUpdate = true;
texture2.needsUpdate = true;

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry,
  new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
   
      fade: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
      texture1: { value: texture1 },
      texture2: { value: texture2 }
    
    },
    vertexShader: `

      // Define the uv we want to pass to our fragment shader
      varying vec2 vUv;
    
      void main(){
    
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
   
      }
  
    `,
    fragmentShader: `
   
      // Read our uv and textures, as well as fade value
      uniform sampler2D texture1;
      uniform sampler2D texture2;
      uniform float fade;
      varying vec2 vUv;
    
      void main(){
    
        // Read our pixel colors as rgba
        vec4 t1 = texture2D( texture1, vUv );
        vec4 t2 = texture2D( texture2, vUv );
     
        // Mix our pixels together based on fade value
        gl_FragColor = mix( t1, t2, fade );
     
      }
    
    `
  })
);

scene.add( cube );

camera.position.set( 0, 0, 5 );
camera.lookAt( scene.position );

renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  targetState = targetState === 1 ? 0 : 1
});
renderer.setSize( 512, 512 );

render();

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The shader code is so familiar,  the code struct is so helperful, great!

Comment: what if I use two colors instead of two textures?  I define the uniforms in fragment shader vec4 type , but it fails to compile. code gist here https://gist.github.com/haolly/02de6dc530f00343a725fe39852a0f3d

Comment: @liuhao I replied to your gist, but just for future reference: `THREE.Color` is technically a `vec3` as it contains only `rgb`, so you need to convert them to `vec4` to use them as actual colors. Use `vec4 color1 = vec4( myColor0, 1.0 )` to add the full alpha value. Then work with those `vec4`.  And make sure you define them as `uniform vec3 myColor0`.